# How to get the AX1675i Wifi module to work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. (Acer predator PH315-55)

Tags: 20.04, wireless, iwlwifi

When installing the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the AX1675i model which comes in the Acer predator PH315-55 laptop the wifi adapter shows missing even though it is there inside the laptop and is working well in windows boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this problem was that there is no Linux support available for the AX1675 driver officially but since it is equivalent to the AX210 drivers and they do have Linux support, installing them solved the problem.

```
1. Go to "https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html" 
2. Download the Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz firmware.
3. After downloading the driver. Open your “Downloads” folder and extract the file in the same folder.
4. Once extracted, go into the directory where your extracted files are present and open the terminal from inside the folder.
5. From the terminal, install the wifi 6 ax210 driver via the following command 
(use the appropriate file name for the ucode file):
    
    $ sudo cp iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware
   
The command copies the “iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.uncode” file to  “/lib/firmware” 
which ultimately installs the intel wifi 6 ax210 driver on Linux. 

This should install the driver onto your system. 
Reboot your system, and it will start working!
```

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY MAKE IT WORK !!!!

The thing is, the kernel version of my Linux was 6.2 and it was not working at all, even after a lot of attempts. So I discovered that in the version 6.4 it had a patch (6.4.7) to include this wifi module version.

The diff:
https://github.com/AnggaR96s/stable-queue/blob/5c5b3711f967a3a24a1184d67521b44d783f1e7f/releases/6.4.7/wifi-iwlwifi-pcie-add-device-id-51f1-for-killer-1675.patch#L10

I used the **Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer** to install the kernel version 6.4.10 (following [this tutorial](https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-4-on-ubuntu-heres-how)), rebooted the laptop and it worked just fine!!

**If after you reboot your system, you have the error "bad shim signature, you need to load kernel first", just disable the secure boot and it will work!!**